# Inject onsubmit event in form javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to inject a onsubmit event with a fuction to be call in the following form dynamically, when the action url is = "https://someurl/somepath". how can it be done in javascript?

Note: there might be some instance the the form doesnt have class.

```
<form action="https://someurl/somepath" method="GET" class="someclass">

 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:-

```
var form = document.querySelector("form")[0];

if(form.action == "https://someurl/somepath"){
   form.addEventListener("submit", myfunction);
}
```

Comment: there might be some instance that there is no class. I edited my question.

Comment: I edited my answer. It will select the 1st form element in HTML.

Comment: how can i get the parameters that was sent or the queryString?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array contains the URLs that you want to allow submitting.

```
const form = document.querySelector('.someclass');
const url = form.action;
const URLs = [
  'https://someurl/somepath',
  'https://someOtherurl/someOtherpath',
];

if (URLs.includes(url)) form.addEventListener("submit", func);
```

You can also select form by action:

```
const url = 'https://someurl/somepath';
const form = document.querySelector(`form[action='${url}']`);

form.addEventListener("submit", func);
```

Comment: there might be some instance that there is no class. I edited my question.

Comment: \how can i get the parameters that was sent or the queryString?

Answer (score 0):

Check the action and stop submittal if not allowed using `event.preventDefault`. Snippet uses [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)

```js
document.addEventListener("submit", handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.type === "submit") {
    if (evt.target.action.endsWith("somepath")) {
      evt.preventDefault(); // demo, remove for real use
      return console.log("allowed");
    }
    
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log("not allowed");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
form {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<form action="https://someurl/somepath" method="GET" class="someclass">
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<form action="https://someurl/otherpath" method="GET" class="someclass">
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<form action="https://someurl/yeatanotherpath" method="GET" class="someclass">
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: @Kooilnc how can i get the parameters that was sent or the queryString?

Comment: That's a different question imho